# Calculate exponents of 16 using only bitwise operators

Tags: java, hex, bit-manipulation

If I was using a loop that looked like this:

```
String string = "DF3";
for (int i = string.length() - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
        int c = string.charAt(i);

        convertedHex += (i << 4);

}
```

How would I calculate `Math.pow(16, i)` without using `Math.pow()`, another loop, or multiplication? Specifically, how can I do it with **only** bitwise operators?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert `i`-th power of 16 by observing that 16=2<sup>4</sup>, hence 16<sup>i</sup>=2<sup>4*i</sup>, and that 2<sup>i</sup>=`1<<i`. Therefore, 16<sup>i</sup>= `1<<i*4`, which can be rewritten as `1<<(i<<2)` to avoid multiplication.

However, you do not need to compute the powers of 16 directly. You can construct the number by repeated multiplication by 16 in the loop, i.e.

```
convertedHex = (convertedHex << 4) + nextHexDigit;
```

**Note:** `int c = string.charAt(i)` gives you the UNICODE code point for the character, not the value of the corresponding digit. Use this code instead:

```
int nextHexDigit = Character.digit(string.charAt(i), 16);
```

Comment: I can't use multiplication.

Answer (score 0):

Given that `1 << i` is same as `Math.pow(2, i)`, you can simply use `1 << (i * 4)`. However, note that this is assuming that overflow does not occur for the datatype you are using.

In case of `int`, a maximum value of 7 is allowed for i, and in case of `long`, a maximum value of 15.

Comment: I should have specified further--I can't use any multiplication whatsoever.

Comment: In that case, `(i * 4)` can be replaced with `(i << 2)`.